# Woocommerce - add last category name to product name

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

How to display last category name for product ?
I want to combine the product name with the name of the last category
https://screenshotscdn.firefoxusercontent.com/images/0b7c1ee5-6b2a-4e26-bf9e-1c44084abc5c.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
// get all product cats for the current post
$categories = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' ); 

// wrapper to hide any errors from top level categories or products without category
if ( $categories && ! is_wp_error( $category ) ) : 

// loop through each cat
foreach($categories as $category) :
  // get the children (if any) of the current cat
  $children = get_categories( 
      array ('taxonomy' => 'product_cat', 'parent' => $category->term_id )
  );

  if ( count($children) == 0 ) {
      // if no children, then echo the category name.
      echo $category->name;
  }
endforeach;

endif;
```

Comment: when try use your code on flatsome theme for woocommerce, I can't add this function.
This is fragments of code :
        function flatsome_product_page_title(){
        if(get_theme_mod('product_header') !== 'featured-center') return;

        echo '<h1 class="product-title entry-title">'.get_the_title().'</h1>';